# Bot Framework V4 IActivityLogger

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, botframework

Do We have any interface like IActivityLogger (V3) , in V4 to log all user activities?

I wanted to log all user queries and bots response in my cosmos db. I was able to do this in V3 using IActivityLogger interface.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interface in V4 is [ITranscriptLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.itranscriptlogger)

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Builder
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Transcript logger stores activities for conversations for recall.
    /// </summary>
    public interface ITranscriptLogger
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Log an activity to the transcript.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="activity">The activity to transcribe.</param>
        /// <returns>A task that represents the work queued to execute.</returns>
        Task LogActivityAsync(IActivity activity);
    }
}
```

Once you have an **ITranscriptLogger** implementation, it can be added to the middleware stack using [TranscriptLoggerMiddleware](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.cs)

```cs
var transcriptStore = new MyCosmosTranscriptStore(config.TranscriptConnectionString, storageContainer);
var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(transcriptStore);
...
.AddSingleton(_ => transcriptStore);
```

Then add it to the adapter with `adapter.Use(transcriptStore);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have ILoggerFactory interface in V4 which is used to log all user activities.

For example:

```
private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

// Create a logger for the application to use.
ILogger logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ConversationHistoryBot>();

// Catches any errors that occur during a conversation turn and logs them.
options.OnTurnError = async (context, exception) =>
{
    logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception}");
    await context.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.");
};

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    
    app.UseDefaultFiles()
       .UseStaticFiles()
       .UseBotFramework();
}
```

Attached here is the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) repo where you can find the conversation-history which uses the above interface.